# Can't parse a statement in an article on coalgebras and umbral calculus

Tags: reference-request, terminology, hopf-algebras, coalgebras, umbral-calculus

This question is cross-posted from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4873055/cant-parse-a-statement-in-an-article-on-coalgebras-and-umbral-calculus).

I am reading Nigel Ray's "Universal Constructions in Umbral Calculus" (1998, published in "[Mathematical Essays in Honor of Gian-Carlo Rota](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817638725)", page 344). The article reads:

> We define an *umbral calculus* $(C, r)$ to consist of a coalgebra $C$ in $\mathcal{C}_{R}$ [the category of coalgebras over a commutative ring $R$] and an *evaluation* functional $r$ in $C^*$ (the dual $\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(C, R)$).
> For added convenience we insist that $C$ be *supplemented*, in the sense that it is equipped with a summand of *scalars* whose projection is a counit $\epsilon: C\to R$, and that $r$ acts on this summand as an identity.

I am completely lost beginning at "that $C$ be *supplemented*". What is meant here by *scalars*? Are scalars elements of the ring $R$? What is the *summand* of scalars? Summand with respect to what operation, what objects are being summed? Is it an operation? An object? A subset? What does it mean for a "summand" to have a "projection" that is a map from $C$ to $R$? Projection by what map? This terminology is neither explained nor used neither before nor after, and I wasn't able to google what is a "supplemented coalgebra".

Comment: I think “summand of scalars” means something like $C=R\oplus C’$. Think of how a polynomial algebra in its degree zero component has a copy of the coefficient field.

Comment: What would it mean, then, for this subspace to have the counit, a map from $C$ to $R$, as a projection? Something like "counit acts as identity on $R$ injected in $C$"?

Comment: Yes, projection means it should be the identity on the $R$ component of $C$.

Comment: So, do I understand it correctly that here "supplemented coalgebra" means just "coaugmented coalgebra"?

Comment: The *coaugmentation* $u:R\rightarrow C=R\oplus C'$ is the inclusion in the first direct summand since $\varepsilon\circ u=\text{id}$.